# Trying to call a method in a contract, invalid address error/Type Error

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, javascript

Hi I have a deployed contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract adderr {
    int total;
    function adder() public {
        total = 0;
    }
    function getTotal() constant returns (int){
        return total;
    }
   function addToTotal(int add) returns (int) {
       total = total + add;
       return total;
   }
   function calculateProof(string document) constant returns (bytes32) {
       return sha256(document);
   }
```

}

I am trying to call the method `addToTotal`, so I do:

`var address = Contract address` (This is 100% correct i've triple checked)
`var abi = contract abi interface` from remix, then taking line breaks out
`var contract = eth.contract(abi).at(address)`
Then I call with `contract.addToTotal(5)`
and get the error

```
Error: invalid address
at web3.js:3930:15
    at web3.js:3756:20
    at web3.js:5025:28
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:5024:12
    at web3.js:5050:18
    at web3.js:5075:23
    at web3.js:4137:16
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
```

NOTE: When i try the `getTotal` method there is no problem the returns the correct value

I have also tried to do:
`var contract = new web3.eth.contract(abi,address)`
To instantiate my contract, however this time when i try to call I get the error

```
TypeError: 'getTotal' is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I have tried called methods with both `contract.addToTotal` and `contract.methods.addToTotal(5)`

Would appreciate any help in this matter!

Comment: Could you give us a link to your ABI? (creat a gist for example) Also, do you use web3js 1 or 0.2?

Comment: How are you passing the ABI? It should be passed as a json object, if you send a string it will error out, you can use `JSON.parse(abi_as_string)`. Also which version of web3js are you using? They have different ways to instantiate contracts.

Comment: Yeah i was passing the correct ABI in json format directly from Remix, i still am unsure as to why this didnt work but Ive gotten around the problem now by using .getData(param)